# If the Admin leaves a WhatsApp group, how is the next Admin chosen?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

I am in a WhatsApp group. Now, due to some quarrel in the group, the group Admin has left. Now, I have become the Admin of the group all of a sudden.

How is the next Admin chosen? Is it purely random or does the previous Admin choose someone before leaving?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's purely random

From [WhatsApp FAQ](https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/kaios/26000196/?category=5245251)

> If you are the only group admin and you exit a group, a participant is chosen **at random** to become the new admin

(Emphasis Supplied)